# Positioning JTable to (x,y) location in a JPanel inside a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I want to place the JTable inside a JPanel at the right-centered portion of the screen but not able to display the JTable inside JPanel, only the blank JPanel is displaying.PLease help.

```
TableModel tmodel = new DefaultTableModel(arr,columns)
{
public Class getColumnClass (int column) 
{
Class returnValue;
if((column >=0) && (column<getColumnCount()))
{
returnValue = getValueAt(0,column).getClass();
}
else 
{ 
returnValue = Object.class;
}
return returnValue;
}
};
JTable jtable = new JTable(tmodel);
RowSorter <TableModel> rsorter = new TableRowSorter <TableModel> (tmodel);
jtable.setRowSorter(rsorter);
JScrollPane jspane = new JScrollPane(jtable);
jp.add(jtable);
jp.add(jspane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
jp.setLayout(null);
jp.setLocation(700,150);
jp.setSize(600,350);
jf.getContentPane().add(jp);
}
};
EventQueue.invokeLater(runner);
}
```

Comment: How did you create the JPanel object?

Comment: What is jf? and Have you added setVisible(true) ?

Comment: Don't use `null` layouts, they cause no end of trouble. Furthermore, don't add the table anywhere once you have set it the viewport of a scroll pane; just add the scroll pane to where you want the table to be.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems in your code. First one: you are trying to add `JTable` instance 2 times, first into the scrollpane and second into the panel.
Second one you should set your layout, you cannot use null layout.
An example code could look like that:

```
    jp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JTable jtable = new JTable(tmodel);
    RowSorter <TableModel> rsorter = new TableRowSorter<>(tmodel);
    jtable.setRowSorter(rsorter);
    JScrollPane jspane = new JScrollPane();
    jspane.setViewportView(jtable);
    jp.add(jspane,BorderLayout.CENTER);     
    jp.setLocation(700,150);
    jp.setSize(600,350);
    jf.getContentPane().add(jp);
```